# gMock for Dummies - How to Getting Started? (Visual-Studio-2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest, visual-studio-2019, googlemock

I tried to create a very simple Mock Class as per Getting Started of [gMock for Dummies](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html).

1. I created a new blank project in VS Studio 2019
2. I ran the package manager `Install-Package gmock -Version 1.8.1` as per this answer [Configure GoogleMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053105/how-to-configure-googlemock-in-visual-studio-2017-after-already-installing-googl)
3. The packages.config file that got created

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
   <packages>
       <package id="gmock" version="1.8.1" targetFramework="native" />
   </packages>
   ```
4. I created 1 file Source.cpp

   ```
   class Turtle {
       virtual void PenUp();
   };

   void Turtle::PenUp() {
       return;
   }

   #include "gmock/gmock.h"

   class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
   public:

       MOCK_METHOD(void, PenUp, (), (override)); // not working see Pic1

       MOCK_METHOD0(PenUp, void()); // not working see Pic2

   };
   ```

The 2nd example tries a syntax like this answer [How to mock method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500334/how-to-mock-method-with-optional-parameter-in-google-mock/45049665)

Pic1:

[image: Pic1 - MOCK_METHOD]

Pic2:

[image: Pic2 - MOCK_METHOD0]

Comment: Problem is specific your your machine/code. Your example simply [works in both versions](https://godbolt.org/z/uGRhtp). Something bad is done in code which you didn't show.

Comment: Also there are couple things which should be done in a [bit different way](https://godbolt.org/z/0mNXfE).

Comment: I copy&pasted your code samples into my Source.cpp and Visual Studio will still tell me "Function Definition for 'MOCK_METHOD' not found."

also there is nothing in the project except the Source.cpp and packages.config that I showed [link](https://ibb.co/YXyNcbZ)

Comment: Just to be clear: is this a build issue or just a warning shown by IDE? AFAIK Visual Studio IDE without ReSharper installed shows some false positive warnings when it sees some macros from gtest/gmock.

Comment: I copy&pasted this code: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/Il-Fxc)

and it gave me this complie output:
`1>Source.cpp 1>C:\Users\Amin Abromand\source\repos\Project2\Project2\Source.cpp(14,25): error C2061:  syntax error: identifier 'PenUp' 1>C:\Users\Amin Abromand\source\repos\Project2\Project2\Source.cpp(14,42): error C4430:  missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 1>C:\Users\Amin Abromand\source\repos\Project2\Project2\Source.cpp(14,42): warning C4183:  'MOCK_METHOD': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'`

Comment: I have just recognized, if you chose an x86 msvc compiler, the compiler explorer is not giving any output :(

Comment: Your gMock-for-dummies Link is outdated and broken. New link is   http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html

Comment: I have updated the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to compile my solution now:

1. I created a new blank project in VS Studio 2019
2. I cloned the google repo [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest)
3. In the project properties I added C/C++ add. include directories

   ```
   path\to\repo\googlemock
   path\to\repo\googlemock\include
   path\to\repo\googlemock\include\gmock
   path\to\repo\googlemock\include\gmock\internal
   path\to\repo\googletest
   path\to\repo\googletest\include
   path\to\repo\googletest\include\gtest
   path\to\repo\googletest\include\gtest\internal
   ```
4. I created 1 file Source.cpp

   ```
   #include "gmock/gmock.h"
   #include "gtest/gtest.h"

   #include "src/gmock-cardinalities.cc"
   #include "src/gmock-internal-utils.cc"
   #include "src/gmock-matchers.cc"
   #include "src/gmock-spec-builders.cc"
   #include "src/gmock.cc"

   #include "src/gtest.cc"
   #include "src/gtest-death-test.cc"
   #include "src/gtest-filepath.cc"
   #include "src/gtest-port.cc"
   #include "src/gtest-printers.cc"
   #include "src/gtest-test-part.cc"
   #include "src/gtest-typed-test.cc"

   class Turtle {
   public:
       virtual ~Turtle() {}
       virtual void PenUp() = 0;
   };

   class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
   public:

       //MOCK_METHOD0(PenUp, void()); // working =)
       MOCK_METHOD(void, PenUp, (), (override)); // working =)

   };

   int main(int, const char* []) {
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Idea came from [this blog post](https://blog.many-monkeys.com/using_gmock_with_visual_studio_cpp_unit_test_framework/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it, the **Windows** way. You need to install the Windows `cmake` here https://cmake.org/download/. Because the `cmake` bundled in Cygwin is **NOT** compatible to **Visual Studio**, you need the `cmake.exe` for Windows and then run it from DOS terminal. I have `cygwin` for other things, but for all things **Visual Studio**, it needs to be done the Window's way in the DOS terminal. I am using **Visual Studio 2019**.

```
git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git
```

Then open DOS terminal, granting PATH can find `cmake.exe` already. Goto where you cloned the `googletest` repo.

```
cd googletest
mkdir c:\opt
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:\\opt ..
```

It shall generate the usual `googletest-distribution.sln` Visual Studio solution file. It is now time to use the mouse. Double-click on this solution file, and it shall launch **Visual Studio IDE**. Build **ALL_BUILD** and **INSTALL**. The `ALL_BUILD` will produce `*.lib` files and the `INSTALL` will copy these files to `c:\opt` location. After this, the gtest/gmock lib and headers shall be located in `C:\opt\` folder.

Comment: When I build googltest as you suggested - the resulting solution builds fine. But I need a `x86` version, so I added `-A Win32` option. In this way the resulting solution doesn't compile due to `gtest-port.h(2194,20): error C2039: 'int_t': is not a member of 'std'`. Any idea how to properly build a `x86 version` of googletest?