# How to mock method with default parameter in Google Mock C++?

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest, googlemock

How to mock a method with optional parameter in Google Mock? For example:
I try this, but it does not work:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{ 
public:
    virtual void set_enable(const int test, const bool enabled = true ) const;
};

template <typename T>
class MockA : public A<T>
{
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD2_T( set_enable, void(const int test, const bool enabled ) );
    void set_enable(const int test /*, const bool enabled = true*/ ) const
    {
        set_enable( test, true);
    }
};
```

Then call:

```
MockA mockA;
EXPECT_CALL(mockA, set_enable(_,true)).Times(Exactly(1));
```

When I run test, it show "Segmentation fault"

Comment: Did you check where it crashes in the back trace using a debugger?

Comment: `MockA` is a templte so given example should not compile (it doesn't). Please provide [mcve], so we could see actual problem, you can start with this link: https://godbolt.org/z/G3M9dj9cK

Comment: Why `A` is template if template parameter is not used?

Comment: Quick patching the code from your question, by filling gaps I can come up with,  works without any segmentation faults (address sanitizer is enabled): https://godbolt.org/z/P7TEP6EEb and I had to fix a lot to make it compile. So looks like problem is not Mock but, production code you are trying to test. We can't help you fix code which is not shown.

Comment: @MarekR thank you for your help, so my mock is ok, i need to recheck my source, something wrong with it. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock method with optional parameter in Google Mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500334/how-to-mock-method-with-optional-parameter-in-google-mock)